# Using AWK to add a new column with values to a csv file without creating empty new lines in between rows

Tags: shell, awk, csv

I would like to add a new column to the end of a csv file and populating the column with values. I have used the following codes and it ends up showing new blank lines in between each record. Please let me know how to avoid these newly added blank lines.

```
awk -F "," 'NR == 1 {$5="MonthYear"}{ if (NR>1){split($2,a,"[/ ]");$5=a[1]"/"a[3]}}1' RS='\r' OFS="," Test.csv > Test1.csv
```

tried with both RS='\n' and RS='\r\n' and still get the same result

Input file - Test.csv

```
Id  Day UserId  ItemId              
1   12/1/17 0:03    2323    tv              
2   12/14/17 7:10   4546    frr             
3   1/22/18 14:11   2421    fdf             
4   2/16/18 13:36   4545    dfdf                
5   3/5/18 10:47    1232    dfsdf
```

Actual output file - Test1.csv

```
Id  Day UserId  ItemId  MonthYear

1   12/1/17 0:03    2323    tv  12/17

2   12/14/17 7:10   4546    frr 12/17

3   1/22/18 14:11   2421    fdf 1/18

4   2/16/18 13:36   4545    dfdf    2/18

5   3/5/18 10:47    1232    dfsdf   3/18
```

Expected Output - csv

```
Id  Day UserId  ItemId  MonthYear       
1   12/1/17 0:03    2323    tv  12/17       
2   12/14/17 7:10   4546    frr 12/17       
3   1/22/18 14:11   2421    fdf 1/18        
4   2/16/18 13:36   4545    dfdf    2/18        
5   3/5/18 10:47    1232    dfsdf   3/18
```

Without RS, the output is jumbled up like this:

```
,MonthYearrId,ItemId
,12/17/17 0:03,2323,tv
,12/174/17 7:10,4546,frr
,1/182/18 14:11,2421,fdf
,2/186/18 13:36,4545,dfdf
5,3/5/18 10:47,1232,dfsdf,3/18
```

Comment: Hi @thinkingsavvy. Would you please double check your command. The output is different than the output "Actual output file - Test1.csv"  that you had provided in the question?

Comment: Hi @Goro. You are correct! I copied the output from excel. The output using cat is.  Id,Day,UserId,ItemId,MonthYear

1,12/1/17 0:03,2323,tv,12/17

2,12/14/17 7:10,4546,frr,12/17

3,1/22/18 14:11,2421,fdf,1/18

4,2/16/18 13:36,4545,dfdf,2/18

5,3/5/18 10:47,1232,dfsdf,3/18

Comment: You are using is `RS`which is the record seperator. What you want is `FS` which is the field separator.

Comment: @thinkingsavvy, thanks! please try the commands below and let us know!

Comment: Your comment claims that the field separator is a semicolon (;) but the file contents posted in the question use a tab(?) or spaces(?) as field separator. Which is the correct one?.

Comment: @Isaac its a csv file with , as field separator.

Comment: Have you tested if there are `carriage return` characters in your file ? Take a look with `cat -A Test.csv`.

Comment: @Isaac I tried `cat -A Test.csv` it gives me error `cat: illegal option -- A
usage: cat [-benstuv] [file ...]` I am using bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way in which I can reproduce your problem is if the file actualy contains semicolons as delimiters **and** each line ends in a `\r\n` pair. When that happens, using the `\r` as the RS causes the `\n` to be on the next line.

Source file used:

```
Id,Day,UserId,ItemId
1,12/1/17 0:03,2323,tv
2,12/14/17 7:10,4546,frr
3,1/22/18 14:11,2421,fdf
4,2/16/18 13:36,4545,dfdf
5,3/5/18 10:47,1232,dfsdf
```

The simplest solution is to remove the `\r` in the file (maybe using dos2unix).
Easier to do so inside awk:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/\r/,"")}; NR==1 {print $0,"MonthYear"}; NR>1 {print $0,$2"/"$4}' FS="[,/ ]" OFS=, Test.csv
Id,Day,UserId,ItemId,MonthYear
1,12/1/17 0:03,2323,tv,12/17
2,12/14/17 7:10,4546,frr,12/17
3,1/22/18 14:11,2421,fdf,1/18
4,2/16/18 13:36,4545,dfdf,2/18
5,3/5/18 10:47,1232,dfsdf,3/18
```

Comment: @thinkingsavvy Then, please, accept it as an useful answer (it is the tick (`✓`) below the votes). [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by removing the blank records from the outputfile using
`sed '/^ *$/d' Test1.csv > Test2.csv`

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` approach

```
$ awk '{print $0,NR==1?" MonthYear":substr($2,0,index($2,"/"))substr($2,length($2)-1)}' Test.csv
Id  Day UserId  ItemId  MonthYear
1   12/1/17 0:03    2323    tv 12/17
2   12/14/17 7:10   4546    frr 12/17
3   1/22/18 14:11   2421    fdf 1/18
4   2/16/18 13:36   4545    dfdf 2/18
5   3/5/18 10:47    1232    dfsdf 3/18
$
```